# Keras error with shape of neural network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

Please help with the following code piece, error seems to be related to shape of output but I am not sure what should I change, my input is X and lable for training data is y(see in code)

```python
def model(load, shape, checkpoint=None):
    """Return a model from file or to train on."""
    if load and checkpoint: return load_model(checkpoint)

    conv_layers, dense_layers = [32, 32, 64, 128], [1024, 512]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='elu', input_shape=shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    for cl in conv_layers:
        model.add(Convolution2D(cl, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Flatten())
    for dl in dense_layers:
        model.add(Dense(dl, activation='elu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")
    return model

net = model(load=False, shape=(100, 100, 3))
X = ['/path/to/img/file',...]
y = [[1.2, 4.5],[<num1>,[num2>]]] 
net.fit_generator(_generator(256, X, y), samples_per_epoch=1000, nb_epoch=2)
```

Leads to following error:

```python
net.fit_generator(_generator(256, X, y), samples_per_epoch=1000, nb_epoch=2)
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (256, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to do a binary classification. Your labeled Data has the shape (batch_size, 2). I would gues that is always 0,1 or 1,0 depending on which class is right. But your model only has one output. If you're using mean squared array your model need as many output neurons as last dimension in your labels => 2.
You can now either transform your label data in something of shape (batch_size, 1) (or only (batch_size) I'm not sure) or you increase the number of neurons in your output layer.

Also if I'm right, that you want to do a binary classification use binary crossentropy as loss function.

Comment: No, I am not doing binary classification. The output label has two individual fields eg. <speed>, <steering>

Comment: Ok, then that‘s how your label has to look, if you want to use mse loss function. The alternative would be to write your own loss function which suits your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

If `y` is of the form `[[1.2, 4.5], ...]`, this will work (instead of the last layer you have defined currently):

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
```

If `y` is either in the form `[1.2, 3.4, ...]` or `[[1.2], [3.4], ...]` you can use the layer you have:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```